# How to expand ComboBox to see hidden childelements without physical click?

Tags: combobox, click, dropdown, form-control

Example Site:
https://ariakit.org/examples/combobox-links

How can I "open" the combobox from the Chrome Dev Tools (or similar) console to show the sub-elements that are hidden until combobox dropdown list is expanded?

`document.querySelector(".combobox")`

Sorry if my terminology is off. I am a novice web scraper and I am not yet fluent with the lingo.

My (eventual) goal is to use AutoHotKey's Rufaydium (WebDriver tool) to automate looping through all childelements to get the "href" link, open each "href" in a new tab, and do standardized actions on each tab.
https://github.com/Xeo786/Rufaydium-Webdriver

I can physically click the combobox with my mouse cursor to get the child elements to display

[What I Want To See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hql8X.png)